# Catching exceptions thrown from scheduled job during test execution

Tags: unit-test, scheduled-apex, exception, scheduled-job, asynchronous-testing

I am curious about how to test a scenario when a scheduled job throws an exception. Imagine this is how the schedulable class looks:

```
global class ExceptionScheduler implements Schedulable {   
    global void execute(SchedulableContext context) {         
            throw new InvalidVariableValueException();
        }
    }
```

In my test method, I schedule the job and try to catch all the exceptions to verify my exception is thrown after `Test.stopTest()` is executed. I tried something like this and the exception is thrown as it should be, but my try-catch does not catch it:

```
@isTest
static void exceptionIsThrown() {
    String jobName = 'ScheduledApexTest';
    String cronExp= '0 0 0 15 3 ? 2022';

    try{
        Test.startTest();
        System.schedule(jobName, cronExp, new ExceptionScheduler());
        Test.stopTest();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.assertEquals(InvalidVariableValueException.getTypeName(), e.getTypeName());
    }
}
```

I guess that is because scheduled code runs asynchronously.

Is there another way to test this scenario and make sure my exceptions get thrown from scheduled code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As we can assume that Salesforce test the `System.schedule` method so you don't have to, some or all of your test methods can directly invoke your `Schedulable`:

```
new ExceptionScheduler().execute(null);
```

though as AFAIK `SchedulableContext` can't be instantiated you'll need to pass `null`. Then the normal try/catch will work as its a synchronous call.

Comment: Thanks, in my case this is good enough, since I don't use the context in the body of my execute() method. I will leave the question open for some time to see if someone can find a solution that could work including the call to System.schedule() to preserve the context.

Comment: `SchedulableContext` is actually an interface, so you can implement it in a mock class if you do want to test against it.

Answer (score 2):

When `stopTest()` runs, it causes execution of any asynchronous calls made since `startTest()`, so there is guaranteed to be a finished [`AsyncApexJob`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_asyncapexjob.htm) record in your test's database.  Unfortunately, it doesn't look like it has a single "exception" field, but you could check the `Status`, `Extended Status` or `Number of Exceptions` fields:

```
@isTest
static void exceptionIsThrown() {
    String jobName = 'ScheduledApexTest';
    String cronExp= '0 0 0 15 3 ? 2022';

    Test.startTest();
    ID jobID = System.schedule(jobName, cronExp, new ExceptionScheduler());
    Test.stopTest();

    System.assert([select ExtendedStatus from AsyncApexJob where ID = :jobID]
                         .ExtendedStatus.contains('InvalidVariableValueException'));
}
```

Comment: Yes, this could give me the exception to compare, but unfortunately, unless I somehow catch the exception as well and stop it from propagating, the test will still fail because the exception will break the execution and test will be reported as failed.

Comment: @AndrejLučanský Interesting, I didn't think the scheduled job failing would cause the test to fail.